# android copying database from internal to external storage return empty database

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to copy my databases from my internal storage to external, but it's not copying the database. It's just creating a new empty sqlite file. Any ideas what I'm missing actually?

Here is what I'm using :

```
    public static void copyFile(String currentDBPath, String backupDBPath){
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and using it like this :

```
File database = new File("/sdcard/Stam/Data/");
        database.mkdirs();
        RPCCommunicator.copyFile("/data/data/" + this.getPackageName()+ "/databases/stam_sys_tpl.sqlite","/sdcard/Stam/Data/system.sqlite");
```

So using this, it's creating the system.sqlite, but it's empty without any tables. The thing that I want to do is to move the database from it's current directory to a new one without loosing any data.

Any ideas why it's not working properly?

Comment: are u sure extension is .sqlite and not .db?

Comment: It's usually better never to assume that the external storage is called "/sdcard" - always use Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory(). Also, do not manually construct the path to your database file, use Context#getDatabasePath("stam_sys_tpl.sqlite").

Comment: Ok, I've just tried to use it in your way...still creating a new empty file. Is it possible to copy database file to sd card without loosing any data. that's what I need actually. I can copy an empty one from my assets folder, but i need to keep users data.

Comment: What is the output of `dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());`, it returns the number of bytes copied - does it match the actual size? Use a normal InputStream to OutputStream copying loop otherwise..

Comment: tried with three different types of copying, they didn't work. the `dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());` does not match the actual size and when I open the database file it's an empty, without any tables on it...which is really strange.

Comment: Are you closing the `SQLiteOpenHelper` you used to create the database prior to copying it?

Comment: I'm not closing it, I'm just initializing it and tryin to copy to sd card.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Context.getDataBasePath()` to get your db file!

Answer (score 1):

you cannot copy database file to external storage.

you can create a new database in the external storage.

query the internal database and insert in the new database you have created

Comment: That sounds odd. Worked just fine on Android 2.3 with a simple table & straight forward copying.